# converting array to a true/false matrices

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, matrix

I have a data set where each record is a json document with a label, and an array of signals. The signals will vary for each record:

```
{
    "label":"bad",
    "id": "0009",
    "signals":["high_debt_ratio", "no_job"] 
},

{
    "label":"good",
     "id": "0002",
    "signals":["high_debt_ratio", "great_credit", "no_id_match"] 
},

{
    "label":"good",
    "id": "0003",
    "signals":["low_debt_ratio", "great_credit"] 
},

{
    "label":"bad",
    "id": "0001",
    "signals":["high_risk_loc", high_debt_ratio", "no_job", "no_id_match"] 
}
```

I want to convert this to a matrices that looks like this:

| id | label | high_risk_loc | high_debt_ratio | no_job | great_credit | no_id_match | low_debt_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0009 | bad | false | true | true | false | false | false |
| 0002 | good | false | true | false | true | true | false |
| 0003 | good | false | false | false | true | false | true |
| 0001 | bad | true | true | true | false | true | false |

I created a function but it seems like this would be a common thing to do. Is there a python lib (pandas, scikit, etc.) that does this for you? I'd rather use something from a package but i'm not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read your json data with `json_normalize` in data frame using `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(['your json data'])
```

Your data frame look like this

```py
  label    id                                            signals
0   bad  0009                          [high_debt_ratio, no_job]
1  good  0002       [high_debt_ratio, great_credit, no_id_match]
2  good  0003                     [low_debt_ratio, great_credit]
3   bad  0001  [high_risk_loc, high_debt_ratio, no_job, no_id...
```

Now we need unique list of value for `signals` column and loop over with its availability and base on that need to insert `True` or `False` in value of particular column... also removed `signals` column after getting final datas

```py
for i in list(set(df.signals.sum())):
    df[i] = df.signals.apply(lambda x: i in x)
df.drop('signals',axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
-:output:-
  label    id  low_debt_ratio  great_credit  high_debt_ratio  no_id_match  high_risk_loc  no_job
0   bad  0009           False         False             True        False          False    True
1  good  0002           False          True             True         True          False   False
2  good  0003            True          True            False        False          False   False
3   bad  0001           False         False             True         True           True    True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one line solution:

```
d = pd.json_normalize([{
    "label":"bad",
    "id": "0009",
    "signals":["high_debt_ratio", "no_job"] 
},

{
    "label":"good",
     "id": "0002",
    "signals":["high_debt_ratio", "great_credit", "no_id_match"] 
},

{
    "label":"good",
    "id": "0003",
    "signals":["low_debt_ratio", "great_credit"] 
},

{
    "label":"bad",
    "id": "0001",
    "signals":["high_risk_loc", "high_debt_ratio", "no_job", "no_id_match"] 
}])

d.merge(d.signals.apply(lambda x: "|".join(x)).str.get_dummies(sep = "|"), left_index = True, right_index= True)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something for intuitive using sklearn's `MultiLabelBinarizer`, though slightly more verbose:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(df['signals'])
new_col_names = mlb.classes_

# New DataFrame containing 0/1 values of the signals
signals_df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.transform(df['signals']), columns=new_col_names)

# Concatenate with original DataFrame
pd.concat( [df, signals_df], axis=1 )
```